# Fatal Error: "Class not registered" creating COM Object

Tags: php, windows, class, com, registry

I have an app that makes use of third party software using PHP(32 bit PHP) COM object, everything is working fine on my local machine (Windows 7, 64bit).

When I deployed my app to a live server (Windows Server 2012, 64bit) and I try to create my COM object I'm getting the

**Fatal Error:** Cannot create object "Class not registered"

After finding these other SO questions:

[Class not registered error from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929925/class-not-registered-error-from-php)

[Failed to create COM object 'X': Class not registered in another WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449897/failed-to-create-com-object-x-class-not-registered-in-another-wamp)

I have ran `regsvr32.exe` (the 32bit version) for my DLL with message prompt indicating successful registry.

And also verified that the CLSID exists in all the proper places in the registry (registry entries are the same on both machines):

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID
```

Does anyone know why I am still receiving this error? Is it due to Windows Server 2012 OS?

Comment: Your techtalk link below fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with hosting php websites in windows but I know for IIS hosted websites I get this error for a myriad of reasons.  Some of which you've mentioned above.  When hosting in IIS I know there is a setting that needs to be set to **True** called "Enable 32 bit applications"

[image: Enabled 32 bit applications]

Also you want to make sure if you are transferring this file from another computer that the file is unblocked as this will cause a lot of headaches as well and strange errors.

[image: Unblock files]

Sometimes what I do as well is to write a simple test gui that calls this com dll to eliminate anything related to running it as a website.  If you are able to access it with the gui application it could be something security related to running it as a website if the user the website is running under is different than the user launching the gui application.

### Edit

Also try the article mentioned here:
http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

It seemed to have helped you judging by the comment below.

Comment: Turns out my server was running a 64 bit version of PHP, not 32 bit like I had thought. this article: http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/ ended up fixing my problem, thanks for the feedback tho, I'll go ahead and award the bounty since you were the only response, perhaps you can update the answer with the link I provided and Ill also mark it as correct for future visitors